# Unity3D C# Negative Lerp?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lerp

I am wanting to lerp the variable that controls my animations speed so it transitions fluidly in the blend tree.

```
 void Idle()
     {
         _agent.SetDestination(transform.position);
             //Something like the following line
         _speed = Mathf.Lerp(0.0f, _speed, -0.01f);
         _animationController._anim.SetFloat("Speed", _speed);
     }
```

I'v read that you can't lerp negatives, so how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `t` value in a lerp function between `a` and `b` typically needs to be in the 0-1 range. When `t` is 0, the function returns `a` and when `t` is 1, the function returns `b`. All the values of `t` in between will return a value between `a` and `b` as a linear function. This is a simplified one-dimensional lerp:

```
return a + (b - a) * t;
```

In this context, negative values of `t` don't make sense. For example, if your speed variable is `4.0f`, the result of `lerp(0, 4, -0.01f)` would be:

```
0 + (4 - 0) * -0.01
```

which returns `-0.04`.

**The simplest way to solve this issue is to simply flip `a` and `b` instead of trying to use a negative `t`.**

```
_speed = Mathf.Lerp(_speed, 0.0f, 0.01f);
```

---

Another suggestion would be to use [Mathf.SmoothStep](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.SmoothStep.html) and store the original speed instead of applying the function on the constantly changing `_speed` to get a really smooth transition.

Answer (score 7):

I think you're using Lerp bad.

As written in Unity Documentation (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html), you should pass 3 floats, the minimum as first argument, the maximum as second and the time as third.

This third should be beetwen 0 and 1.

Aside from that, you can always make the number negative after lerping it.

Some examples :

- In case you want from -10 to 10, lerp from 0 to 20 and then substract 10.

  float whatever = Mathf.Lerp(0f, 20f, t);

  whatever -= 10f;
- In case you want from 0 to -50, lerp from 0 to 50 and then make it negative.

  float whatever = Mathf.Lerp(0f, 50f, t);

  whatever = -whatever;

Answer (score 2):

Well, you cannot actually.

A psuedo-codish implementation of a Lerp function would look like this:

```
float Lerp(float begin, float end, float t)
{
    t = Mathf.Clamp(t, 0, 1);
    return begin * (1 - t) + end * t;
}
```

Therefore, any attempt to give a t value outside of [0, 1], ie. an extrapolate attempt, would be clamped to the valid range.